# Why only the first image fades out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making simple fading effect for my pictures using javascript:

```
const [fadeIndex, setFadeIndex] = useState(0);
const providers = ["google_search", "bing_search", "yahoo_search", "duck_search"];

const startFadingEffect = () => {
    let fadeInterval = setInterval(function() {
      fadeOutEffect(providers[fadeIndex]);
    }, 3000);
  };

const fadeOutEffect = provider => {
    let fadeTarget = document.getElementById(provider);
    let fadeEffect = setInterval(function() {
      if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
      }
      if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
        fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.05;
      } else {
        clearInterval(fadeEffect);
      }
    }, 100);
    if (fadeIndex < 3) {
      let x = fadeIndex;
      x++;                    // isn't increasing
      setFadeIndex(x);
    }
  };
```

I'm expecting to see images fading out one by one depending on current `fadeIndex`.
In reality what I see is only the first image fading out and it won't carry on others.

I've tried to move the increase logic into main interval:

```
const startFadingEffect = () => {
    let fadeInterval = setInterval(function() {
      fadeOutEffect(providers[fadeIndex]);
      if (fadeIndex < 3) {
         let x = fadeIndex;
         x++;                   // isn't increasing
         setFadeIndex(x);
    }
    }, 3000);
  };
```

but I got the same result. Only the first image fades out.

What's the problem ?

Comment: This does not look like a valid way to use `useState`. React hooks can only be used with react function components. And if you are using React, you should not try to set style attributes on dom elements like that. React has its own shadow dom, and style should be set using props. Gradiual fade is much easier to implemented with css transition instead of javascript setInterval and dom manipulation.

Comment: I agree there are more ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 0):

well...after thought
I think I found the issue

you use const at

```
//I thought this was some kind of react thing...
const [fadeIndex, setFadeIndex] = useState(0);
```

and then

```
if (fadeIndex < 3) {
    let x = fadeIndex;
    x++;
    setFadeIndex(x);
}
```

why add and use `x` here instead of

```
setFadeIndex(fadeIndex+1);
```

or

```
fadeIndex++;
```

cus `fadeIndex` is `const`, means it's immutable
you must got jshint error or js error
`Attempting to override 'fadeIndex' which is a constant. (E013)`
`Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.`
and try to solve it in wrong way

the result of try to use `setFadeIndex` to set `fadeIndex`
cus it's immutable, `setFadeIndex` won't work
so `x = fadeIndex` will always be `0`

also using `setInterval` like is messy and confusing

try use [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

if you don't need fadeIndex on other react thing
this can be done by pure js

```
const providers = ["google_search", "bing_search", "yahoo_search", "duck_search"];

// use async function, so you can use promise to wait
const startFadingEffect = async () => {
    // cus you use if (fadeIndex < 3), I guess it just same as providers array length
    // if you need to use other array
    // try use querySelectorAll to select elements you want to fade
    for (let element_id of providers) {
        let fadeTarget = document.getElementById(element_id);
        if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;

        // await in async function means wait until this Promise resolve
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            let fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
                if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
                    fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.05;
                } else {
                    console.log("clear this one and wait 3sec before go to next");
                    clearInterval(fadeEffect);
                    resolve(); // end this promise
                }
            }, 100);
        });

        // wait 3000ms before next
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
        // the setinterval in your startFadingEffect is 3000ms
        // so I guess you want delay 3000ms between each one
    }
};
// if you need to keep doing this
// use other function to check and call startFadingEffect()
```

this demo may help you understand how it work

```js
const test_array = ["google_search", "bing_search", "yahoo_search", "duck_search"];
const test_async = async () => {
    for (let element_id of test_array) {
        let dummy_opacity_value = 1;
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            let fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
                console.log(`target_id:[${element_id}], value(opacity):[${dummy_opacity_value}]`);
                if (dummy_opacity_value > 0) {
                    dummy_opacity_value -= 0.25; //speed up
                } else {
                    clearInterval(fadeEffect);
                    console.log("clear this one and wait 3sec before go to next");
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 500); //slow down
        });
        await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000));
    }
};
test_async();
```